# How to checked radio button on edit in ReactJs using componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

Opening a modal in edit with all the value but radio button is not checked while condition is true. What am I doing wrong here and should `this.state.value` be checked?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MDBContainer, MDBBtn, MDBModal, MDBModalBody, MDBModalFooter, MDBInputGroup } from 'mdbreact';
import InputForm from './productsinputfield';
import Collection from './collectionpopup';
import Product from './productpopup';
import axios from 'axios';
```

This is the class:

```
class ModalPage extends Component {
        
    addToArr = [{ id: 1, shippingValue: 20, taxValue: 20, shipingStatus: 0, taxStaus: 1 }]
    state = {
        modal13: false,
        tag_name: 'Rajat Srivastava',
        status: false,
        valueStatus: false,
        quantityStatus: false,
    }

    // This is the function which is calling in every render what
    // I want whenever this will be called on edit then radio buttons
    // should be checked:

    componentDidMount() {
        
    // The Props Data Is Coming From Another Component
    if (this.props.sendRowData) {
    
    // This condition is true but still unable to checked radio button:

     if(this.props.sendRowData.cart_status == 1){ 
      
    
     this.setState({ valueStatus : true });
    
     }else if(this.props.sendRowData.cart_status == 2){
    
     this.setState({quantityStatus : true});
     }
    }
    }
      
    showPopUP(nr) {
    let modalNumber = 'modal' + nr
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        [modalNumber]: !this.state[modalNumber],
        status: !this.state.status,
    });
    this.setState({ name: 'Rajat Srivastava' });
    }
```

This is my JSX code

```
    render() {
    return (
    <div className="row">
    <div className="col-lg-2"></div>
    <div className="col-lg-8">
    <MDBContainer>
    <MDBBtn color="primary" className="floatDiv" onClick={() => this.showPopUP(13)}>
    Create Discount Tag
    </MDBBtn>
    
    {
    this.state.status && <MDBModal isOpen={this.state.modal13} toggle={() => this.showPopUP(13)} size="lg">
    <MDBModalBody>
    <MDBContainer size="lg">
    <form action="#" onSubmit={this.saveTagSettings}>
    <h6>Set Products <span style={{ color: "red" }}> * </span></h6><br />
    <div className="card   card-header">
    <div className="form-check card-header">
    <div className="marginLeft">
    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="product" id="product" checked={this.state.valueStatus} value="1" onChange={(e) => this.handleProductRadio(e, 'minCartVal')} />
    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="product">
    Minimum Cart Value
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div className="form-check card-header">
    <div className="marginLeft">
    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="product" id="product" checked={this.state.quantityStatus} value="2" onChange={(e) => this.handleProductRadio(e, 'minCartQua')} />
    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="product">
    Minimum Cart Quantity
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <MDBBtn color="primary" type="submit">Save Tag</MDBBtn>
    </form>
    </MDBContainer>
    </MDBModalBody>
    <MDBModalFooter>
    <MDBBtn color="secondary" onClick={() => this.showPopUP(13)}>
    Close
    </MDBBtn>
    </MDBModalFooter>
    </MDBModal>
    }
    
    </MDBContainer>
    </div>
    <div className="col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>
    );
    }
        }
        
        export default ModalPage;
```

Comment: Maybe somehow the `this.setState({quantityStatus : true});` is also been calling so the radio is not checked.

Comment: Ya I already solved it but yes you are right and thank you so much.